# Lock MyISAM table for maintenance

Tags: mysql

I have a MyISAM table that has to be cleaned once in a while (a total of ~5M rows out of 12M rows are being deleted).
Afterwards, I have to optimize table, and I know that OPTIMIZE TABLE goes faster if I drop indexes first.
The problem is,

```
ALTER TABLE t1 DISABLE KEYS;
--> here
OPTIMIZE TABLE t1;
--> or here
ALTER TABLE t1 ENABLE KEYS;
```

MySQL may decide to serve some other queries, it leads to multiple slow non-indexed table scans, delaying further steps.

So how do I lock the table for other threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how do I lock the table for other threads?

You can use [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/lock-tables.html):

```sql
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE;
```

But, as noted:

> If you use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html) on a locked table, it may become unlocked. For example, if you attempt a second [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html) operation, the result may be an error `Table 'tbl_name' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`. To handle this, lock the table again prior to the second alteration. See also [Section C.5.7.1, “Problems with `ALTER TABLE`”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table-problems.html).

Comment: Looks like it did the trick! Thanks.

"[LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE lock: ... Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released..." 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM lacks transactional support, so this is impossible to do reliably (there are a lot of DDL-level operations that will unlock silently). That's why you should schedule maintenance like this at night so you don't catch the extra load in busy hours.

You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though - you're asking about a self-devised solution to a problem you're having, instead of asking for a proper solution to the problem.

Alternative options to solve the underlying problem are:

- Doing the cleanup far more frequently - in smaller batches the load shouldn't be really noticeable
- Doing the `OPTIMIZE` step only at night and the cleanups frequently during the day.
- Since you consider downtime acceptable apparently (as you suggest locking yourself) you could even consider renaming the table temporarily during the duration - it's a prehistoric way of assuring nobody else touches the table, but it'll work.

If you describe your *actual problem* in more detail we might be able to give better solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd like to clarify. Cleanup procedure itself does not pose a problem - it's adaptive and does not even bother anyone. The question is about table optimizing. OPTIMIZE TABLE for MyISAM, as explained in manual, 'reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data', not recreating it, as it does for InnoDB. And that's why it goes way faster when dropping indexes first...

Comment: I just wanted to know, if there's any way not to let anyone to interfere these 3 queries.

Comment: Hmm yeah I got MyISAM and InnoDB confused on the `optimize` internals, my apologies. I'll fix the answer.